# ReactJS - How to render single object from an array using id?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

In react app, I am trying to get single row from an array using id but it doesn't work.

```
const result = [
 {id: 0, important: false, name: "Shruthi R", phone: "9834233433", email: "shruthi@gmail.com", work: "NicheSoft", city: "Mysore"},
 {id: 1, important: false, name: "Shivay", phone: "9442233166", email: "shivay@yopmail.com", work: "MicroSoft", city: "Mumbai"},
 {id: 2, important: false, name: "Yash Sindhya", phone: "7455454354", email: "yash@yopmail.com", work: "AirVoice", city: "Pune"},
 {id: 3, important: false, name: "Rajat", phone: "8456546555", email: "rajat@gmail.com", work: "Airtel", city: "Delhi"},
 {id: 5, important: false, name: "Surya S", phone: "9956546546", email: "surya@gmail.com", work: "Vodafone", city: "Chennai"},
 {id: 6, important: false, name: "Paridhi", phone: "8856544422", email: "paridhi@gmail.com", work: "MicroTech", city: "Lucknow"},
];
```

My `onEditClick` function is as shown below, here I want single(matching) row from an `result` using `id`

```
onEditClick = (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.id);
}
```

Comment: do I understand correctly that you want to get object by id?

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided `event.target.id` contains the relevant ID, you can use array method `find()`:

```
onEditClick = (event) => {
  const clickedResult = result.find(({id})=>id===parseInt(event.target.id));
  console.log('clickedResult', clickedResult);
}
```

Comment: When I convert `event.target.id` to `parseInt(event.target.id)` then this will works..